# Statistics Binomial with Probability Distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be a binomial random variable with $n=2, θ=\frac14$. Find the probability distribution function of $Y=(X^2)+2$.

Comment: What have you tried? Please demonstrate some effort of your own, and you are more likely to get help.

Answer (score 3):

That $X$ is a [binomial random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with $n=2$ means that $X$ only takes on the values $0,1,2$ with positive probability. Furthermore, since you're given that $\theta=\frac14$, you're able to calculate $P(X=0), P(X=1)$ and $P(X=2)$ explicitly.

Now, find out which values $Y$ can take on and calculate the probabilities using what you know about $X$.

Comment: $P(Y=y) = P(X^2+2 = y) = P(X=\sqrt{y-2})$. Now you need to think on the answer of Stefan in order to find the set of possible $y$.